# format '%lf' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'double *'

Tags: c

I've tried searching this error code but I'm new to C and the answers don't really clear it up for me. I'd appreciate if someone could point out where I'm going wrong as when I print out any value inside the do while loop it gives a value of 0. Thanks!

```
initial_x_pos = 300;
initial_y_pos = 800;
x_pos = initial_x_pos;
y_pos = initial_y_pos;

gravity = 1.62;

position = sqrt(pow(x_pos, 2) + pow(x_pos, 2));
influence = 3.14 * 50 * 50;

GFX_SetColour(WHITE);

GFX_MoveTo(initial_x_pos, initial_y_pos);

do {
    time += 1;
    y_pos = initial_y_pos - (vel_y * time) / 2;
    x_pos = initial_x_pos + (vel_x * time) / 2;
    GFX_DrawLineTo(x_pos, y_pos, 3);
    GFX_UpdateDisplay();
    distance = sqrt(pow(y_pos - (y + 312), 2) + (pow(x_pos - (x+440), 2)));
    printf("%lf\n", &distance);
    printf("%lf\n", &vel_x);
} while (vel_x != 10000000000);
```

Comment: `%lf` should be `%f` and `&distance` should be `distance`.

Comment: Note alternative to  `sqrt(pow(x_pos, 2) + pow(x_pos, 2))` --> `hypot(x_pos, y_pos);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `l` modifier is ignored for conversion specifier `%f` in `printf`, which expects a `double` value. `float` arguments are automatically converted to `double` when passed to `printf` or any other varadic functions.

You did not post the complete code to a function, the type of the `distance` variable is unknown, but passing its address via `&distance` is always wrong.  You may have copied the code for reading it via `scanf()` where the `%lf` is required for type `double` and the address of the destination must be passed.

Here is a corrected version:

```
int time = 0;
double distance;
double initial_x_pos = 300;
double initial_y_pos = 800;
double x_pos = initial_x_pos;
double y_pos = initial_y_pos;

double gravity = 1.62;

double position = sqrt(pow(x_pos, 2) + pow(y_pos, 2));
double influence = 3.14 * 50 * 50;

GFX_SetColour(WHITE);

GFX_MoveTo(initial_x_pos, initial_y_pos);

do {
    time += 1;
    y_pos = initial_y_pos - (vel_y * time) / 2;
    x_pos = initial_x_pos + (vel_x * time) / 2;
    GFX_DrawLineTo(x_pos, y_pos, 3);
    GFX_UpdateDisplay();
    distance = sqrt(pow(y_pos - (y + 312), 2) + (pow(x_pos - (x + 440), 2)));
    printf("%f\n", distance);
    printf("%f\n", vel_x);
} while (vel_x != 10000000000);
```

Note however that `vel_x` is not modified in the loop, and comparing `double` value with `==` is discouraged as the floating point computations have limited precision.

Comment: Request to add: "l modifier is ignored for conversion specifier %f"  for `printf()`.  `'l'` is important with `scanf()`.